# Does all inexact differential equations have an integrating factor?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

In this wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inexact_differential_equation) , it was written that inexact differential equations can be solved using integration factors.

Does all inexact differential equations have an integrating factor?

I remembered learning that integrating factors of the form $\mu(x)$ or $\mu(y)$, i.e. depending on one variable, can be easily found for an inexact differential equation of the form $$A(x,y) dx+B(x,y)dy=0.$$

However, if integrating factors cannot be found in the forms of $\mu(x)$ and $\mu(y)$, other methods are used to solve the differential equation. In such cases, does a valid integrating factor  exist?